# Нужны ли запятые после слов "Комиссии" и "ТМЦ"?

Tags: запятые

Комиссии при списании ТМЦ особое внимание обратить на наличие документов.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые не нужны, но для ясности после слова "Комиссии" желательно поставить *двоеточие*, поскольку всё последующее содержание предложения - *указание*, адресованное этой комиссии. В исходном же виде предложение с первого раза не читается, поскольку "комиссии" поначалу воспринимается как "комиссионные отчисления, возникающие при списании ТМЦ". Лучше изменить порядок слов и добавить глагол:

> При списании ТМЦ комиссии *следует* обратить особое внимание на наличие
>   документов.